# coroutine was never awaited using Flask.SocketIO

Tags: python, flask, websocket, cors, flask-socketio

I am setting up Flask like this

```
app = Flask(__name__, directory)
CORS(app)
socketio = SocketIO(app, cors_allowed_origins='*')



async def status_checker(ip_address):
    param = '-n' if platform.system().lower() == 'windows' else '-c'
    command = f'ping {param} 1 {ip_address}'

    # Execute ping asynchronously
    process = await asyncio.create_subprocess_shell(
        command,
        stdout=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE,
        stderr=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE
    )

    # Wait for the ping command to complete
    status = await process.wait()
    return status == 0

@socketio.on('check_all_devices')
async def handle_check_device_status(data):
    print('***handle_check_device_status call!')
    ip_address = '192.168.11.1'  # Example IP address

    device_status = await status_checker(ip_address)
    print('device_status ->', device_status)
    status_response = 'Hello World'
    print('status_response', status_response)
    await socketio.emit('device_status', status_response)
```

The idea is from the front end I am emitting 'check_all_devices' to the server to get some response back

```
useEffect(() => {
        console.log('connecting to Flask socket')
        // Initialize Socket.io client connection
        const socket = io('http://localhost:5000'); // Replace with your Flask server URL

        console.log('Start listening')
        // Listen for 'device_status' event from server
        socket.on('device_status', (data) => {
            console.log('Received data:', data);
        });

        console.log('emitting message')
        // Emit 'check_all_devices' event to server
        socket.emit('check_all_devices', {}); // Send an empty object or any required data
        console.log('emitted!')

        // Clean up function
        return () => {
            socket.disconnect();
        };
    }, []);
```

From the terminal I can see that there is some initial handshake stuff going on, but I get this error when I try to break out of Flask

```
RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'handle_check_device_status' was never awaited
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
```

Is there some correct way of handling asyncio with flask and socketio ?

I have tried setting `async_mode='asyncio'` but it did not help me as I got this error

```
ValueError: Invalid async_mode specified
```

Comment: Flask-SocketIO does not support asyncio. Use regular sync functions with it.